# Is there a way to change Ubuntu 17.10 theme

Tags: themes, appearance

Just downloaded and installed Ubuntu 17.10 and I was wondering if I could change the look. To look like the Ubuntu 17.04 or just change it, as it is. PS. I prefer the Ubuntu 17.04 look.(UNITY)

Comment: Which part do you want to change and to what?